# how to change the version of eclispe from 1.8 to 1.7?

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I was change the current java machine to 1.8 and the eclipse work fine , Now i want to back to 1.7 so i do this steps :

down vote

In the START menu type "regedit" to open the Registry editor

Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" on the left-hand side registry explorer/tree menu

Click "SOFTWARE" within the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" registries

Click "JavaSoft" within the "SOFTWARE" registries

Click "Java Runtime Environment" within the "JavaSoft" list of registries here you can see different versions of installed java

Click "Java Runtime Environment"- On right hand side you will get 4-5 rows . Please select "CurrentVersion" and right Click( select modify option) Change version to "1.7"

now when I run the eclipse it did not run and show the error message :
Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

so what I can do ?

Comment: Recent versions of Eclipse **must** be run using Java 8. Java programs you run from within Eclipse can use any versions of Java you choose - is that what you want to do?

Comment: Wrong approach anyway. You control the Java version to start eclipse with via the eclipse.ini configuration file.

Comment: @greg-449  you are right the eclipse need java 8 , so I must to change the version of appliction run within to 1.7 , how I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Eclipse (Neon and Oxygen) must be run using Java 8.

Programs you run from within Eclipse can use any Java you have installed.

First you must tell Eclipse about each Java you have installed. Do this in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs'.

You can then set the Java used for a particular project in the Properties for the project. In the 'Java Build Path' property page on the 'Libraries' tab change the 'JRE System Library' entry to the Java you want to use.

You can also choose the Java used when running the program in the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog by setting the JRE on the Main tab in the entry for your program.

Comment: I do like you say but the error :  Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion' has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required. Error: could not find java.dll Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment. not remove

Comment: Well you have messed with the Windows Registry, you need to put it back the way it was before. I can't help you with that as I don't run Windows.

Answer (score 0):

finally it work , I do the next steps :

Use the eclispe.ini file (folder where the eclipse binary resides)
Add the -vm option with the path of the jre to startup with

i.e Windows
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe

i.e Linux
-vm
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java

and it work like Charm

I hope that help some one in the future